# React action always dispatch before resolve all promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux, action

I have an async action in react, it will call a method to get a promise list, each promise also have a list data, I want to resolve all data from each promise in this promise list to a list. There should be two loop. Then dispatch an action with the data list. I initial an empty array before resolve the promise list. But the function always dispath the empty array before saving all data into this list. Can anyone teach me how to avoid this situation? Thanks.

My code looks like this:

```
export const fetchNearbyMeetups = (lat, lng) => async(dispatch) => {

try {
    const promises = await getMeetupsByRegion(lat, lng);
    const matchingMeetups = [];
    Promise.all(
        promises.map(async(snapshots) => {
            snapshots.then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.map(((doc) => matchingMeetups.push(doc.data())));
            });
        }),
    );
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_NEARBY_MEETUPS,
        payload: matchingMeetups,
    });
} catch (err) {
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_NEARBY_MEETUPS_ERR,
        payload: null,
    });
}
```

};

Comment: `snapshots.then((snapshot) => {` is neither `return`-ed nor `await`-ed. So, the callback `async(snapshots) => {` just returns (a promise that resolves to) `undefined` and the inner content will not be waited for.

Comment: Did you try `Promise.all().then('/*do stuff*')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `await Promise.all(`

When you have a list of async results you'd usually do something like this:

```
Promise.all(
  [1,2,3].map(asyncFunction)
).then(
  asyncResults=>dispatch(someAction(asyncResults))
)
```

Or for async functions:

```
const asyncResults = await Promise.all(
  [1,2,3].map(asyncFunction)
);
dispatch(someAction(asyncResults))
```

Mutating a temporary value looks wrong to me.

Answer (score -1):

try using

await Promise.all(....)